# Showing independence of random variables

Tags: self-study, independence

The configuration space is given by the
binary sequences of length N, i.e.,
$Ω_N =\{ω = (ω_1,...,ω_N ) ∈ \{−1,+1\}^N\}$
Write $X_k (ω) = ω_k , 1 ≤ k ≤ N, ω ∈ Ω_N$
to denote the projection on the k-th component of ω, which is to be thought of as the step of the random walk
at time k. As probability
distribution on $Ω_N$ we take the uniform distribution, i.e., $P_N (A) = |A|2^{−N}, A ⊆ Ω_N$. It follows that for $1 ≤ k_1 < ··· < k_n ≤ N$ and $x_{k_i}
∈ \{−1, 1\}, i = 1,...,n, P(X_{k_1} = x_{k_1},...,X_{k_n} = x_{k_n}) = 2^{N−n}2^{−N} = 2^{−n}$

> Q: Use this to conclude that $X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n$ are independent and identically distributed with $P(X_k =1) = P(X_k = −1) =\frac{1}{2}$

The definition I've been asked to use is: A finite collection of random variables $X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n$ is mutually independent if the sets $(X_j ∈ A_j )$ are mutually independent for all events $A_j$ in the ranges of the corresponding $X_j$.

I'm struggling to understand and use this definition, what exactly are the sets "$(X_j ∈ A_j )$", and are the events $A_j=\{-1,1\}$?

So far, I've understood that with reference to my question, $(X_j ∈ A_j )=\{ω \in Ω_N  | X_j(ω) \in A_j\}= \{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_j \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\}$. To prove that these sets are mutually independent I have done this: $P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{i} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\} \cap \{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{j} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})=P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{i} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{j} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})$ for all pairs $(i, j), i,j, \in \{1,2,...,N\}, i \neq j. -(1)$

$ P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{i} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\} \cap \{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{k} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\} \cap  \{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{j} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})=P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{i} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})P (\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{k} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{j} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\}) \forall (i,j,k), i,j,k \in {1,2,...,N}, i \neq j \neq k$ and so on till

$P(\cap_{i \in \{1,2,...,N\}}\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{i} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})=\prod_{i=1}^NP(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{i} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})$

Is this okay? What justification should I give for the equalities in these equations? Intuitively I understand that whether the ith R.V. takes the value $1$ or $-1$ has no influence on what the jth R.V. takes, but I'm struggling to write it mathematically. Can someone please help?

Comment: "$(X_j\in A_j)$" is a conventional abuse of mathematical notation: it's a shorthand for $\{\omega\in\Omega_N\mid X_j(\omega)\in A_j\}.$  The notation "$\{-1,1\}$" refers to the set whose only elements are $-1$ and $1.$  All you need to do is apply a definition of independent events.

Comment: @whuber I didn't understand what $A_j's$ are, the events are $A_{j_1}=1,A_{j_2}=-1$?

Comment: They are arbitrary events.  By definition, an event is a measurable set, which in this case would be any subset of $\Omega_N.$

Comment: In the definition, it's given that $A_j$ denotes all events in the ranges of the corresponding $X_j$. So in my problem, $X_j$ has two outcomes, and those two outcomes comprise of the events $A_j$ isn't it? @whuber

Comment: No, because two *outcomes* determine four *events:* namely, $\emptyset,$ $\{-1\},$ $\{1\},$ and $\{-1,1\}.$ Notice, too, that the event $A_j = \{1\}$ (for instance) really contains $2^{N-1}$ outcomes, because it's designating *sequences* of values and this notation is only restricting the value of the $j^\text{th}$ term in the sequence.

Comment: Okay, understood. So I've to show that these sets: $\{ω \in Ω_N  | X_j(ω) \in A_j\}= \{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_j \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\}$ are mutually independent. I'm not sure how to show that, I know the way to show n events are mutually independent would be to consider the probability of the intersection of every combination of the n events and show that it splits up into the probabilities of each event?  Is that what I'm required to do? @whuber

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @whuber Should I just write $P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{a_i} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\} \cap \{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{a_j} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})=\frac{1}{2^{N-2}}=P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{a_i} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{a_j} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})$ for all pairs $(a_i, a_j), P(\{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{a_i} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\} \cap \{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{a_j} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\} \cap  \{ω \in Ω_N  | ω_{a_j} \in \{\phi, \{1\},\{-1\},\{-1,1\}\}\})=$ 1/2^(N-3)=product of probabilities forall triples (ai,aj,ak) & so on?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I've made the necessary changes. Please take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of independence involves two concepts: *events* and *probabilities.*  This is the case even for the definition of independent random variables.

**Let's review.**  A random variable $X:\Omega\to R$ with values in some measure space $R$ determines a collection of relevant events; namely, the inverse images of measurable sets $\mathcal B \subset R$ of possible values $X$ can attain, $X^{-1}(\mathcal B) = \{\omega\in\Omega \mid X(\omega)\in \mathcal B\}.$  This collection is often denoted $\sigma(X).$

A pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ is *independent* when for any $\mathcal E\in \sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal F\in\sigma(Y)$ the probabilities multiply:

$$\Pr(\mathcal E \cap \mathcal F) = \Pr(\mathcal E)\Pr(\mathcal F).$$

**The problem you face in applying this definition is two-fold:** first, you have $n$ variables, not just two.  Second, there can be a lot of events to consider.  To address the first problem let's consider the two-variable case and hope the ideas generalize.  To address the second problem we need a shortcut.

This shortcut is available because all your variables are binary: with 100% probability their values are in $\{-1,1\}\subset \mathbb R.$  Thus, although there are uncountable many $\mathcal B \subset \mathbb R$ you might need to check, there are really only four kinds:

1. When $-1\notin \mathcal B$ and $1\notin \mathcal B,$ $X_j^{-1}(\mathcal B) = \emptyset.$
2. When $-1\in \mathcal B$ and $1\notin \mathcal B,$ $X_j^{-1}(\mathcal B) = X^{-1}(\{-1\}) = \{\omega\in\Omega\mid X_j(\omega) = -1\}.$  *This is the set of all sequences with $-1$ in the $j^\text{th}$ position.*
3. Similarly when $-1\notin \mathcal B$ and $1\in \mathcal B,$ $X_j^{-1}(\mathcal B)$ is the set of all sequences with $1$ in the $j^\text{th}$ position.
4. When $\{-1,1\}\subset \mathcal B,$ $X^{-1}(\mathcal B) = \Omega.$

Because axiomatically $\Pr(\emptyset)=0$ and $\Pr(\Omega)=1,$ there's nothing to check in cases (1) and (4): the equation in the definition of independence reduces to $0=0$ (in the first instance) or $\Pr(\mathcal E) = \Pr(\mathcal E)$ or $\Pr(\mathcal F) = \Pr(\mathcal F)$ (in the second instance), all of which are guaranteed by the reflexive property of equality.

To deal with cases (2) and (3) (and anticipating the generalization to more than two variables), prove the following lemma:

**Given a collection of positions $1\le i_1 \lt i_2\lt \cdots \lt i_k\le n$ and specified values $b_{i_j}\in\{-1,1\},$ $j=1,2,\ldots, k,$ the chance that a sequence has those values in those positions is $2^{-k}.$**

The demonstration that any two of the $X_j$ are independent is this:

> Let $i\ne j.$ The chance that a sequence has a specified value $b_i$ in position $i$ is $2^{-1}.$  The chance it has a specified value $b_j$ in position $j$ is also $2^{-1}.$  The chance that it has *both* the value $b_i$ in position $i$ and $b_j$ in position $j$ is $2^{-2} = 2^{-1}\times 2^{-1}.$

I leave the generalization to $k\gt 2$ variables to you.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way I can prove the independence definition you've written from the one I've mentioned?

Comment: The definitions are identical -- there's nothing to prove.

Comment: Okay, I can prove the generalization by induction right?

Comment: That would be the rigorous approach, yes.